# What is the $(PackageConfiguration) variable in a Visual Studio project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-runtime, environment-variables

I ran into a linker error (Couldn't open sqlite3.lib) when making a WinRT application.  The funny thing is, it only happens in a new configuration that I made (Master, as opposed to Debug or Release).  I cloned the new configuration from Release, so it should be identical except for a few preprocessor defines.  I found the following entry as a default in my "Library Directories" section under "VC++ Directories"

> $(FrameworkSDKRoot)..\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\SQLite.WinRT81\3.8.0.2\DesignTime\$(PackageConfiguration)\$(PlatformTarget)

However, I can't find any information on what the `PackageConfiguration` variable actually expands to.  I guessed it might be Debug / Release but the folders at that location on the file system are Debug and Retail.  If I add another entry with "Retail" instead of `$PackageConfiguration` then I can build the program properly, but it seems strange.  Does anyone know how this variable is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This value comes from the SQLite.WinRT81.props file located in the SQLite extension SDK which is usually installed here:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\SQLite.WinRT81\3.8.2\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\neutral

On my machine the contents look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageConfiguration Condition="'$(Configuration)' == ''">Debug</PackageConfiguration>
    <PackageConfiguration Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">Debug</PackageConfiguration>
    <PackageConfiguration Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">Retail</PackageConfiguration>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IncludePath>$(FrameworkSDKRoot)\..\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\SQLite.WinRT81\3.8.2\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral;$(IncludePath)</IncludePath>
    <LibraryPath>$(FrameworkSDKRoot)\..\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\SQLite.WinRT81\3.8.2\DesignTime\$(PackageConfiguration)\$(PlatformTarget);$(LibraryPath)</LibraryPath>
    <PropertySheetDisplayName>SQLite.WinRT81, 3.8.2</PropertySheetDisplayName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalDependencies>sqlite3.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Excellent find!  That makes things a pain in the ass to define custom configurations to be shared among team members though ><  I wish they could have had a catch all in there...